# Please help me with the merge trigger for Contact object, where a Contact can have case associated

Tags: trigger

merge trigger for Contact object, the merge is required because of duplicate Contact records and the scenario is that a Contact can have a case, therefore there will be a need to reassign that case to the winning Contact record.

Please give me some sample code to understand as to how to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is maintain a merge table(A custom Object) with a winner and loser fields .An admin can just enter the records here .A salesforce ID in winner or loser or an external Id.

A batch class can be designed to delete all loser contact records after re-parenting cases linked to the loser records to the winner records.

Here is the logic you can adapt for this

1)Fetch all the records from merge table and have a Map of winner and loser record Ids

2)Query for  records from  contact with winner and loser Ids found in merge table .

3)For each of records (Assuming they are winner ) get the corresponding loser Id from map and collect these to fetch cases and delete them.

Hope this small logic helps .